# Sharing transactions beetwen EJB and standalone client

Tags: transactions, glassfish, ejb

How can I configure to share an *entity manager local transaction* generated by a Java 7 stand-alone client, so that calls to a remote EJB 3.1 (configured to use a mandatory transaction) are using that transaction as well?

So after the transaction process on the EJB side has ended, the client can commit the entire operation.

The remote EJB is implemented using Oracle Glassfish 3.1.2

Comment: I can only tell from a JBoss 6 perspective, but why do you not move the entity manager related code to the server-side as well? It would possibly simplify it.

Comment: Not possible since the client is a standalone client with it's own database, hence the need to use a local resource transaction entity manager.